# I'm trying to compile on ideone

Tags: c#

I have problem with ideone compilation [here](https://ideone.com/EW2DpX).
Inside Visual Studio everything is OK. Anybody knows what is the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace CSharpPlayground
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string math = "100 * 5 - 2";
            string value = new DataTable().Compute(math, null).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(value);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quote: _Are you missing `System.Data' assembly reference?_

Comment: @TaW so, is there possible to add assembly reference on ideone? but I already used 'using System.Data'